# How do I fix a mistake in a git branch merge before I push it?

Tags: git, merge, version-control

I have gone through the process of merging my branch into the master. It had conflicts that I fixed, and I completed the merge with --continue.

Before pushing the merge, I realised that I made a mistake in the conflict resolution. I haven't pushed the commit yet, so I should be able to fix it, but I don't want to go through the entire merge process again because it was a lot of work.

I have been thinking about a couple of options:

- Amend the commit, however I have heard that this is dangerous due to the evil merge.
- Reset --soft the merge and modify it and then re-commit. However, this will then be a new set of changes and not a branch commit (so it won't have both parents).

How can I fix my merge commit without going through the entire conflict resolution process again?

Comment: It's okay to amend the commit. Besides, "git rerere" may help in the future, https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/08/rerere.html

Comment: @ElpieKay ooh, that's useful! Thanks, never heard of it before.

Answer (score 0):

Since the merged commit has not pushed to remote repo, **both amend the commit and reset (with hard option) options are ok**.

#### Option 1: Amend the merged cimmit

Commands used as below:

```
#Change the conflict file again
git add .
git commit --amend -m 'message'
git push
```

#### Option 2: Reset the merged commit with `--hard` option

If you want to keep the merge history, I suggest to use **`git reset --hard`** option and then merge again.

- First, let's illustrate by graphs why `git reset --soft` or `git reset --mixed` options are not recommend.

  Assume the commit history for now as below (merged `dev` branch into `master` branch with commit `M`):

  ```
  ...---A---B---C---M  master
         \         /
          D---E---F    dev
  ```

  If you use `git reset --soft HEAD~` or `git reset [--mixed] HEAD~`, the `HEAD` will point to commit `C`, and the working directory has staged changes (for `--soft` option) or modifies changes (for `--mixed` option).

  After you change the file and commit again, the commit history will be:

  ```
  ...---A---B---C---M'  master
         \         
          D---E---F     dev
  ```

  There will show the commit `M'`, and from the commit history, commit `M'` is not a default merged commit (you can not find `dev` branch merged into master branch with default manners).
- While for `git reset --hard HEAD~` it will change the `HEAD` to commit `C` and keep the working tree clean. The commit history will be:

  ```
  ...---A---B---C     master
         \         
          D---E---F   dev
  ```

  Then you can merge `dev` branch into `master` branch again (`git merge dev`). After that, the commit history will be:

  ```
  ...---A---B---C---M''   master
         \         / 
          D---E---F       dev
  ```

  And if you want to merge `dev` branch based on the first time merged result, you can use below commands:

  ```
  git merge dev
  #There has conflicts
  git checkout <commit id for M> -- .
  #Now the conflicts resolution is get as the first time merged
  #Changes files based on the conflicts resolution
  git add .
  git commit
  git push
  ```

Comment: Thanks. In the case of the hard reset, surely I lose all the conflict resolution and have to do it all again?

Comment: Yes, it lose the conflict resolution by default. But there has ways to get the first time conflict resolution. I added the way in the end of my answer. (PS: amend the commit is easier for your situation).